# How to remove cli configs from npm

Tags: node.js, npm, configuration, config, configuration-files

When I run `npm config list`, I can see the following under `; cli configs`:

```
; cli configs
metrics-registry = "http://nexus.mydomain.net:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npm/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/4.4.1 node/v6.10.1 win32 x64"
```

However, when I run `npm config edit`, or even `npm config --global edit`, I don't see those entries that are listed under `; cli configs`. I only see my `; userconfig` if I run `npm config edit`, or my `; globalconfig` if I run `npm config --global edit`.

How can I remove something under the `; cli configs`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly, other than `scope` and `user-agent`, options listed under `cli configs` are typically set on the command line.

```
$ npm --foo=bar config list
; cli configs
foo = "bar"
...
$
```

If you are not passing flags on the command line, some possibilities might be:

- your `npm` command is an alias that has the CLI flags added
- your `npm` command is a wrapper that adds the CLI flags
- your `npm` command was configured at compile time to include these additional configuration options. (Perhaps you are using a version of `npm` that came bundled with something other than a vanilla `node` installation?)

That is not an exhaustive list, but those are the things I would check first.

Comment: Yup, looks like that `metrics-registry` config option has been in there by default, the same way as `scope` and `user-agent`, since [4.1.0](https://github.com/npm/npm/releases/tag/v4.1.0).